# How to check if nginx uses LuaJit and not Lua?

Tags: nginx, lua, luajit

I installed `http-lua-module` with nginx, made a script that works perfectly fine, but now I want to be sure that `nginx`  uses `LuaJit` instead of `Lua` (because my research shows that LuaJit is faster).

I added to the `.bushrc` those lines of code :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/luajit/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LUAJIT_LIB=/usr/local/luajit/lib
export LUAJIT_INC=/usr/local/luajit/include/luajit-2.0
```

I also recompiled nginx and now I just want to be sure that it uses LuaJit.

Comment: `if jit then print'LuaJIT' end`

Comment: Hi Egor, can you tell me where should I write this if statement, I'm new to both nginx and lua

Comment: I'm new to nginx too.  But anywhere in your Lua code you can use `if jit then .. end` statement to check if you run under LuaJIT.

Comment: Thank you, it's really an anwer

Comment: @Egor, the answer box is larger and more convenient to write to.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko Maybe he's allergic to upvotes? ;)

Comment: @greatwolf, could be. I'll start taking his comments and posting them as answers. Not a great move, but could be effective ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Edit your `nginx.conf` file, add a `location` into your `server {}` block:

```
location = /lua {
    default_type text/plain;
    content_by_lua '
        if jit then
            ngx.say(jit.version)
        else
            ngx.say("Not LuaJIT!")
        end
    ';
}
```

Then start your nginx server and then access /lua in curl or in your favorite web browser. If you see outputs like "LuaJIT 2.0.2", then you're using LuaJIT; otherwise, if you see "Not LuaJIT!", then you're using the standard Lua 5.1 interpreter.

Another quicker way is to check the Lua DSO file linked with your nginx executable if dynamic linking is used (which is usually the case):

```
ldd /path/to/your/nginx/sbin/nginx|grep -i lua
```

If you see something like

```
libluajit-5.1.so.2 => /usr/local/openresty-debug/luajit/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2 (0x00007fb3d38f6000)
```

Then you're using LuaJIT.